# Displaying JSON array through ajax (jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, arrays

I'm pretty new to Ajax and JSON and tried to get this to work but can't seem to get the hang of it.

How do I call the json in ajax and display all the info inside the json file?

here's my json file

```
{
  posts: [{
    "image": "images/bbtv.jpg",
    "alter": "BioBusiness.TV",
    "desc": "BioBusiness.TV",
    "website": "http://andybudd.com/"
  }, {
    "image": "images/grow.jpg",
    "alter": "Grow Staffing",
    "desc": "Grow Staffing",
    "website": "http://growstaffing.com/"
  }]
}
```

and the ajax function im using

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "category/all.js",
  dataType: "json",
  cache: false,
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(data) {

    $.each(data.posts, function(i, post) {
      $('#folio').html('<ul><li><div class="boxgrid captionfull"><img src="' + post.image + '" alt="' + post.alter + '" /><div class="cover boxcaption"><p>' + post.desc + '</p><a href="' + post.website + '" target="_blank">More Work</a></div></div></li></ul>');

    });
    initBinding();
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert(xhr.status);
  }
});
```

For some reason, it's only displaying the last item....

Any help in the right direction would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('#folio').html("<ul/>");
$.each(data.posts, function(i,post){
   $('#folio ul').append('<li><div class="boxgrid captionfull"><img src="' + post.image + '" alt="' + post.alter + '" /><div class="cover boxcaption"><p>' + post.desc + '</p><a href="' + post.website + '" target="_blank">More Work</a></div></div></li>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! that worked great.
can't believe i spent couple hours trying to solve this. :)

Answer (score 1):

you are overwriting the html in #folio each loop, you need to concatinate onto it

try adding the UL first then append to the UL a LI for each loop .append() instead

Comment: Thanks for guiding me to the right direction.
it helped me understand exactly what i was doing wrong.