# JSON string through AJAX with jquery, Android

Tags: jquery, android, ajax, json, cordova

Ive been developing an application in android with phonegap. can anyone help me on how can i call my webservice that outputs a JSON string through my android application via AJAX with jquery? thank you very much for the help.

I have this piece of code in my Jscript:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
$.support.cors = true;
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
});

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  timeout: moneTimeout,
  url: "http://10.0.2.2:49878/SampleProject.aspx?p_trxn_type=doLogin&p_phoneNumber="+phoneNumber,
  error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown)
  { 
   alert(xhr.status);
  },
  dataType : "json",
  cache:false,
  async:false,
  success: function (ret)
  {
   try{
    var jsonObj = eval('(' + ret + ')');
    alert(jsonObj.Contacts.Contact['@phoneNumber']);
    alert(jsonObj.Contacts.Contact.LastName);
    alert(ret.Contacts.Contact['@phoneNumber'])
    alert(ret.Contacts.Contact.LastName);
   }
   catch(ex){
    alert(ex.message);
   }
   console.log(ret);
   alert(ret.length);
   alert(ret);
   alert(typeof ret);
   alert("success");
  }
 });
```

and here is the JSON Array the i like to get from my c# webservice,:

```
    {"Contacts":{"Contact":{"@phoneNumber":"0002221111","@countryCode":"1","@typeCode":"73","@type":"Default, Mobile, DefaultContactNumber","@id":"04359c0dcca64638a5fcbb17b386ceed","Salutation":"Mr.","FirstName":"Tom","MiddleName":null,"LastName":"Cruise","NameSuffix":null,"PrimaryAddress":{"Street":{"#cdata-section":"3135 Teodoro Drive"},"Street2":{"#cdata-section":""},"City":{"#cdata-section":"Detroit"},"State":"MS","Country":"US","Postal":"48228"}}}
```

still im getting an alert: error, and it doesnt display the JSON string array from my c# webservice

Comment: Are you willing to use any PhoneGap specific methods or just playn jQuery ajax routines?

Comment: best place to start is here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax.asp

Comment: @Jasper: I've edited my question and added the codes from my jscript.

Comment: @Moss: if you can give me a piece of a sample or a reference that i can depend on? then, why not?

Comment: @Newbie Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319066/displaying-json-array-through-ajax-jquery

Comment: @Newbie Did you set the right internet permission? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">

Comment: @moss: yes, ive done that. as per phonegap's SOP.

Comment: @ALL: ive added the output JSON string that i would to request for my phonegap app in android

Comment: anyone? can you help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your looking for a jquery specific. Maybe this will be helpful

```
$.getJSON("http://yoururl.com?jsoncallback=?",  {
       requestParam: "someValue",  },  function(data) {
        //handle data  
       }
    );
```

For more info, you can check : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

For me, I am using Eclipse Helio, to do my phonegap development on Android. I was writing the code for the following: (Using Youtube API and JSONC format)

```
var myJsondoc = JSON.parse(data.text);
var writeintoHTML = document.getElementById('the_list');
writeintoHTML += myJsondoc.data.items[0].player.default;
```

The editor complain about the "default" as Unexpected Token. At first, i ignore it. and it compile and able to run on my HTC vivid. 
However, when I tested it on my other devices (Galaxy Tab 2.2, Galaxy S 2.3.4) both of them won't work. They all have the error of "Unexpected token default in file....."
Therefore, I changed the code to use YouTube API JSON format. and now all my devices are working now. Just that the JSON format contains more data than I need which I am trying to make the bandwidth usage as low as possible. 
Bottom line, I think the JS will complain about the variable when it has the same name of oprand.